# how to change tinymce.init() to tinymce_custom.init() because conflict name in wordpress wp-tinymce

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I want to use tinymce in my plugin wordpress but it has conflict with builtin wordpress 'wp-tinymce' and wordpress version of tinymce is old
How I can use other instance name like tinymce_custom.init()

I want to build new release from this source https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce ?